# Why does the method count goes up not down when switching from android-support-v4 to v13

Tags: android, android-support-library

When switching from support library v4 to v13 I expected the method count number to go down because now all the methods which are in the SDK version 13+ don't have to be in the support jar anymore. Well I checked what happens when I exchange the v7 against the v13 and here are the method count numbers per package.

When using android-support-v4:

```
 android.support: 10117
    v4: 6402
    v7: 3712
```

and when using android-support-v13:

```
android.support: 10203
    v13: 82
    v4: 6406
    v7: 3712
```

Why are there still all methods from v4 (+4 additional ones?!) included in the v13 version? Reading http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html I thought the version number relates to the API level number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When switching from support library v4 to v13 I expected the method count number to go down because now all the methods which are in the SDK version 13+ don't have to be in the support jar anymore.

No. `support-v13` has everything that is in `support-v4`, plus additional classes that are only relevant for apps with a build target of API Level 13+.

> Why are there still all methods from v4 (+4 additional ones?!) included in the v13 version?

Since the Android Support package pre-dated widespread Android use of things like Maven and Gradle, with transitive dependency support, Google elected to have `support-v13` be a superset of `support-v4`. If they had to do it over again, they might have made `support-v13` be a small JAR that depended upon `support-v4`.